# Trying to add heartbeat for my console application

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, .net-framework-version, apm

A discussion on github mentions that heartbeat is automatically sent when Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.Tracing.DiagnosticsTelemetryModule& is added to the applicationinsights.config file. I want to create an alert in case the app hangs or crashes. Where can I track the heart beat on the AI instance? Also, currently its not sending anything . I am using .net framework 4.7.2. Am I configuring it wrong? I am not able to track the heartbeat on application insights instance. Where can I track it? Can someone provide a snippet for config file?

Answer (score 0):

**Currently, there is an issue involving this telemetry module `AppServicesHeartbeatTelemetryModule` .**

> Can someone provide a snippet for config file?

**There is given a temporary workaround for `WorkerServices`.**

- Add application insights to worker service using `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService()`.
- Not only this `DiagnosticsTelemetryModule` adding to DI and also we need to configure it's heartbeat interval/module using the below snippet:

```
services.TryAddSingleton<ITelemetryModule, DiagnosticsTelemetryModule>();
                    services.ConfigureTelemetryModule<DiagnosticsTelemetryModule>((mod,opt) => mod.HeartbeatInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
                    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
```

- The `TelemetryConfiguration.Active` is not recommended because Worker service is new SDK, its not touching .active or any other static singletons.

> Where can I track it?

After Deploying, Look for "**HeartbeatState**" in **customMetrics**.

**Note:**

- Disabling `DiagnosticsTelemetryModule` will cause the following settings to be ignored: `EnableHeartbeat`, `EnableAzureInstanceMetadataTelemetryModule`, `EnableAppServicesHeartbeatTelemetryModule`.
- Enable ***Azure Monitor*** from the Portal.

**References:**

1. [Configuring or removing default TelemetryModules (HeartBeat Telemetry Issue)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service#configuring-or-removing-default-telemetrymodules)
2. [Enabling Hearbeat in App Services for .NET and .NET Core](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/issues/868)